# Jquery ajax form submit IE issue - Showing download popup

Tags: jquery

I am submitting a form using jquery $.ajax function, it works in all browsers except IE. In IE I am getting File download popup. Does anyone faced this type of issue? Please help. Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem was with jquery submit, I was using it with .live but it has issues in IE browser. Need to remove submit to normal button then it properly submitting the form and no popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved!! The problem was with jquery submit, I was using it with .live but it has issues in IE browser. Need to remove submit to normal button then it properly submitting the form and no popup